# Is there a halachic obligation to meet a spouse through a shadchan?

Tags: halacha, shidduchim-dating

Does it say anywhere in the Shulchan Aruch that Jewish men have to find their spouses through a shadchan, an intermediary?

Comment: No. For example see Igros Moshe(E.H. 4:60) who only prohibits social dating where the two parties are not interested in potentially getting married.

Comment: Many people met their spouses through other means, like neighbors etc. Yaakov met Rachel at a well.

Comment: וּבָאתָ אֶל־הַכֹּהֲנִים הַלְוִיִּם וְאֶל־השדך אֲשֶׁר יִהְיֶה בַּיָּמִים הָהֵם וְדָרַשְׁתָּ וְהִגִּידוּ לְךָ אֵת דְּבַר הַשדוך